# is there a way to create a wavy border radius for a div, and what is the best way to use an image background

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, photoshop

I am trying to make a wavy border for a div like the image I attached [image]

I have tried to slice it and put it as an image background

```
  #section-2{
      background-image: url(../images/section-2bg.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      /* Full height */
      height: 100%;
      /* Center and scale the image nicely */
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

and this is the HTML

```
  <section id="section-2" class="section-prod-comparison">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                 <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
  </section>
```

but the image did not fit the screen and I could not customize it to follow the design
here is the result
[image]

is there any way to make it using CSS ??
or I only have to use the image as a background , so how to make the image background just like the design and responsive as well

thank you

Comment: what you want it to looks like?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP doesn't provide the desired result which make the question not able to answer

Comment: i am looking to make it like the first picture which is the design i am trying to follow @appleapple

Comment: @ AhmedObad The first picture is good, the second is clipped and is also good imo, so there is no problem, what actually doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Put SVG (which has these path and shapes) inside a div container. You can use [this](https://getwaves.io/) site to generate wave svg or just make/find other.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this style in your container.

```
--background: url('./background.png') no-repeat top center / cover;
```